# "A founder of a / the company"

Tags: articles

What article is correct?

1. He is a founder of **a** private company H&M
2. He is a founder of **the** private company H&M?

Answer (score 1):

For the first article (a or the founder) 'you would use 'a' if there had been more than one founder, and 'the' if the person was the only founder.

For the second article (a or the private company), you can use either, but you might use 'a' if you think the person hearing or reading has not heard of H&M, or if there are more than one H&M company, and 'the' if you are sure that they have heard of it, and that there is only one.

If you mean the famous clothing company, then it was founded by one person, Erling Persson (he was **the** founder).